# Fixed elements in modal not staying fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't get these two elements to stay fixed on the modal page. (Click on that image icon just above 'modal#2') https://jsfiddle.net/gkrh0ok0/

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebarRightWork">Information</div>
<button class="remodal-close" data-remodal-action="close"></button>
```

CSS:

```
.remodal-close {
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
transition: color 0.2s;
z-index: 9;
width: auto;
left: 5%;
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
color: #95979c;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
background: transparent;}

.sidebarRightWork {
right:3%;
position:fixed;
top:50%;
z-index:10;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide more information regarding your query.

Comment: I added a picture, hopefully it's a little more clear? I want 'close' and 'information' to stay fixed at 50% vh in the modal window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the .remodal-close only, you can make a sidebar easy with this code.
Add this script to your js file:

```
$('.remodal').scroll(function() {
     var a=$('.remodal').scrollTop();
        a = a += 290;
     $('.remodal-close').css('top', a+'px');
});
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/gkrh0ok0/3/

Comment: When I use that though, it repositions to 290px though. I would like it to keep at 50% of vh so that it moves when resized.

Comment: is it possible to substitute px for %? Say instead of 290 make it 40%?

Comment: The .remodal transform break the position:fixed. It's 'bug' in CSS3. If you are delete these lines in .remodal class, the fixed position is working:     -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); https://jsfiddle.net/gkrh0ok0/6/